# Convert append from in javascript to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, append

I created this simple game where a user is trying to guess a number. I want to use AngularJS frameworks but I am lacking on the basic concepts. For example the first part of my code is a a function that will be used to append the guess to a list of guesses. My issue here is I am not sure how to append to a scope in AngularJS. Here is that part of my original code

```
var numOfAttempts = 6;
var numOfGuesses = 0;
var numberToGuess = "Three";

function listWordsUsed(numberAttempted)
        {
        var userTrials = $('#userGuesses');
        var divisor = $("<p id ='line'><div class='answers'>" + numberAttempted + "</div></p>");
        divisor.hide().appendTo(userTrials).fadeIn(6000);
        return;
    } //End of function listWordsUsed(numberAttempted)
```

I know that I will have to make my variables scopes in order to be used by my aplication, like this

```
$scope.numOfAttempts = 6;
$scope.numOfGuesses = 0;
$scope.numberToGuess = "Three";
```

However I am not sure how to append to a scope variable in AngularjS. Any suggestions? Hints? By the way here is my HTML as I started setting it up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Guess the Number in AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/maincontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='content' ng-app='numberApp' ng-controller='numberController'>
<p>
    <header>
        <h2 align="center">What number am I thinking of?</h2>
    </header>
    <h3>Enter the number:</h3>
    <table>
        <td><input type='text' ng-model='guestGuess' />
        <p>This is: {{guestGuess}}</p>
        <p>This is: {{magicWord}}</p>
        </td>
        <td id="guessBox"><input type="submit" id="guessButton" value="Guess" /></td>
    </table>
    </p>
    <p>
        <h3>Your guesses so far are: </h3>
        <p style="text-align:center;" id="numberGuesses"></p>
        <p id="guessesUsed">You have guessed: <span id="userAttempts"></span> times out six(6) chances.</p>
        <p id="guessesLeft">You have <span id="attemptsLeft"></span> guesses left.</p>
    </p>
   </div>
</div>   
</body>
```

Comment: You just push() into an array and use ng-repeat if you want to display a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/v4ck43HWB77x1xRE78GR)

Basically you just build an array of the guesses you list it with ng-repeat. The rest is just count with .length(), and then do basic math right in the interpolated HTML.

```
  <div ng-controller="numberController">

    <h3>Enter the number:</h3>
        <input type="text" ng-model="guess" />
        <p>Guess is: {{guess}}</p>
        <button ng-click="addGuess()">Guess</button>


    <h3>Your guesses so far are: <span>{{guessed}}</span></h3>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="g in guesses">
        <p>{{g}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <p>You have guessed: <b>{{guessed}}</b> times out six({{allowed}}) chances.</p>
    <p>You have <b>{{allowed - guessed}}</b> guesses left.</p>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dylan, things make so much sense. Now I need to get to nitty gritty of my code!!